# Trace of covariant derivative of a tensor field.

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Let $\mbox{tr} : V^* \otimes V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear map defined by $\mbox{tr}(e^i,e_i) = \langle e^i, e_i \rangle $ where $\lbrace e_i : i \in I \rbrace$ is a basis of $V$ and $\lbrace e^i : i \in I\rbrace$ its dual and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the dual pairing. For a tensor $A = a^i_j e^i \otimes e_j \in V^* \otimes V$ we know that $\mbox{tr} A = a^i_i$.
Now let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $T \in \Gamma^{\infty}(T^{1}_1(M))$ be a $(1,1)$ tensor field on $M$. For a vector field $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ the covariant derivative of $T$ with respect to $X$ is then defined by
\begin{equation}
(\nabla_X T)(\omega, Y) = \nabla_X(T(\omega, Y)) - T(\nabla_X \omega, Y) - T(\omega, \nabla_X Y)
\end{equation}
where $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ is a $1$-form and $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a vector field on $M$. Note that $\nabla_X T$ is a $(1,1)$ tensor field on $M$.
Now I want to show
\begin{equation}
\mbox{tr}(\nabla_X T) = D_X(\mbox{tr }T)
\end{equation}
where $D_X$ is the directional derivative with respect to $X$. Since the trace is defined for $(1,1)$ tensors I choose $(\omega, Y) \in \Omega^1(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and by definition of $\nabla_X T$ and the linearity of $\mbox{tr}$ I get
\begin{equation}
\mbox{tr}(\nabla_X T(\omega, Y)) = \mbox{tr}(\nabla_X(T(\omega, Y))) - \mbox{tr}(T(\nabla_X \omega, Y)) - \mbox{tr}(T(\omega, \nabla_X Y)).
\end{equation}
How can I express each summand in the above equation? I thought of using the decomposition of the tensor field $T = a^i_j d \omega \otimes \partial$ where $a^i_j$ are $C^{\infty}(M)$ functions. I don't see how the decomposition is related to the $C^{\infty}(M)$ function $T(\omega, Y)$. I know that there are two equivalent definitions of a tensor field. The first one is: An $(a,b)$-tensor field on a manifold $M$ is a section of the vector bundle
\begin{equation}
\left(\bigotimes^a T M \right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes^b T^* M \right)
\end{equation}
where the tangent bundle $TM$ occurs $a$ times and the cotangent bundle $T^* M$ occurs $b$ times. The second one is: a $(a,b)$-tensor field defines an $C^{\infty}(M)$-multilinear function. The tensor criterion now says that there is a one-to-one correspondence between those two definitions of a tensor field. I don't understand how I can use the decomposition of $T$ as a tensor field when the covariant derivative of a tensor field is defined through the definition of $T$ being a $C^{\infty}(M)$-multilinear function.
Edit: Using a local frame $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ for $TM$ and $\{e^1,\dotsc,e^n\}$ for $T^*M$ my first thought was:
\begin{align}
\mbox{tr}((\nabla_X T)(p)) &= \mbox{tr}\left(\nabla_X\left( a^i_je^i \otimes e_j \right)(p) \right) \\
&= \mbox{tr}(D_X a^i_j(p) \otimes (e^i \otimes e_j) + a^i_j(p)\nabla_X(e^i \otimes e_j)) \\
&= \mbox{tr}(D_X a^i_j(p) \otimes (e^i \otimes e_j)) + \mbox{tr}(a^i_j(p) \nabla_X(e^i \otimes e_j)) \\
&= \mbox{tr}(D_X a^i_j(p) \otimes (e^i \otimes e_j)) + \\
&+ \mbox{tr}(a^i_j(p) \nabla_X e^i \otimes e_j) + \\
&+ \mbox{tr}(a^i_j(p) e^i \otimes \nabla_X e_j) \\
&= \mbox{tr}(D_X a^i_j(p) \otimes (e^i \otimes e_j)) \\
&= D_X a^i_i(p).
\end{align}
How can I use the definition of the covariant derivative for tensor fields to proof the formula? The definition seems to use the fact that $T(\omega,Y)$ is a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function, but the trace of a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function doesn't make any sense.
Edit: I figured out that the problem is stated poorly such that $\mbox{tr}(\nabla_X T) = D_X(\mbox{tr} T)$ doesn't make any sense. The information needed to understand what this non-sense means can be found here [What is meant by "trace on any pair of indices"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219365/what-is-meant-by-trace-on-any-pair-of-indices?rq=1). So the trace of $T : \Omega^1(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$ is a tensor field $\mbox{tr} T \in T^{0}_{0}(M)$ so a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function satisfying:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{tr}T = \operatorname{trace}(T(\cdot, \cdot))
\end{equation}
where the right hand side is the trace of the endomorphism corresponding to $T(\cdot, \cdot) \in T^1_1(M)$.
So in our case $\nabla_X T$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor field hence the trace is a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function satisfying the above relation.

Comment: $\nabla_X T(\omega,Y)(p)$ is a real number, so taking the trace does not really make sense

Comment: You are right. I corrected it.

Comment: Again $\nabla_X T(\omega,Y)$ is a smooth function on $M$, so the trace does do much. Evaluating at $p$ was not the real issue.

Comment: Use a local frame $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ for $TM$ with dual local frame $\{e^1,\dotsc,e^n\}$ for $T^\ast M$, e.g., $\{\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\dotsc,\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\}$ and $\{\mathrm{d}x^1,\dotsc,\mathrm{d}x^n\}$ with respect to a coordinate chart for $M$. Then $T = a^i_j e^i \otimes e_j$ if and only if $a^i_j = T(e^i,e_j)$ for all $i,j$. In particular, $\operatorname{tr} T = T(e^i,e_i)$.

Comment: $\delta^j_i((T^i_{\,\,j})_{|m}x^m)=(T^j_j)_{|m}x^m$ by definition.